# How do I deal with a subquery that provides more than one line of results?

Tags: mysql

I am having issues trying to write a SQL Statement that finds all the events that a ID is responsible for and then list all the descriptions associated to that event.

```
Person_tbl
PersonID (PK INT)
Name (Varchar eg. "John Smith")

Event_tbl
EventID (PK INT)
SUPV_on_DutyID (FK to PersondID)
Event_Type (VarChar)

Details_Event_tbl
EventID (FK)
DetailsID (FK)

Details_Descrip_tbl
DetailsID (PK INT)
Details_Desc (VarChar)
```

Using my statement I get an error that I am returning too many rows... because it is a case that the Supv can have many Events and Events can have many details.

I need to answer "List all the events and details of events where "Jphn Smith" is responsible".

any help would be appreciated

Comment: use an in clause.   but show your query .. so we can evaluate it

Comment: Use a `JOIN`. See http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example of join operations:

```
 SELECT p.personid
      , p.name
      , e.eventid
      , e.event_type
      , d.details_desc
   FROM `Person_tbl` p 
   JOIN `Event_tbl` e
     ON e.supv_on_dutyid = p.personid 
   LEFT
   JOIN `Details_Event_tbl` j
     ON j.eventid = e.eventid
   LEFT
   JOIN `Details_Descrip_tbl` d
     ON d.detailsid = j.detailsid
  WHERE p.personid = ? 
  ORDER BY e.eventid, d.detailsid
```

Comment: just to clarify, in the select portion you used p. and e. and then later defined them in the from and joins etc. Do I not have to declare what p. and e. are first or type out the table names first?

Comment: I added the full table names and your solution works beautifully. I don't understand the alias used.